# Module PyShark has no attribute 'PipeCapture'

Tags: python, tshark, pyshark

As is known, pyshark is a wrapper for tshark.
With large volumes of traffic, part of the packets are lost due to the limitations of the buffer size (tshark has 2 MB by default)

My idea is as follows:
I want to run tshark with a buffer size like 20MB and pipe the output to my Python script. In this case, instead of LiveCapture, I use PipeCapture as follow:

```
import pyshark
import pandas as pd
import os

r, w = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()
r = os.fdopen(r)    

capture = pyshark.PipeCapture(pipe=r, bpf_filter='udp port 5060')

for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
  print(packet)
```

And i got error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyshark' has no attribute 'PipeCapture' .
```

I checked source code of pyshark here:
https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/blob/master/src/pyshark/capture/pipe_capture.py

Whats wrong?

***UPDATE:***

As @maxkanthauer recommended I do:

```
import pyshark
import pandas as pd
import sys
from pyshark.capture.pipe_capture import PipeCapture

r =  sys.stdin

while True:
    capture = PipeCapture(pipe=r)
    print(capture)
```

and start my script :

```
tcpdump -l  port 5060 -i etho  | python  pyshark_test.py
```

Although i sure that there are many packets the output is :

```
<PipeCapture (0 packets)>
<PipeCapture (0 packets)>
<PipeCapture (0 packets)>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, PipeCapture is not directly under pyshark but rather under pyshark.capture.pipe_capture. In addition, os.pipe() is not a valid value for the pipe parameter. The following should work:

```
import pyshark
import sys
from pyshark.capture.pipe_capture import PipeCapture

r = sys.stdin

capture = PipeCapture(pipe=r)

def print_callback(pkt):
    print(pkt)

capture.apply_on_packets(print_callback)
```

Comment: @harp1814 Cannot comment directly on question. The way you are implementing the functionality, you are just creating capture objects, which are immidiately discarded after the print.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the update, PipeCapture creates a generator, which will always indicate 0 packets before properly reading it. In order to actually read from the FIFO, you iterate over it:

```
capture = PipeCapture(pipe=r)
for packet in capture:
     # do stuff
```

This will execute the loop everytime a new packet comes in.